# log4j configuration for Maven to show logs of tests

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, log4j, stdout

We use the following `log4j.xml` configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="conversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] %-5p [%c{1}]#[%t] %m %n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="some.internal.enterprise.custom.library">
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    </category>

    <!-- Removing the useless logging of "Invalid JavaBean property" -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="WARN"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

And we set up the JUnit test class for logging this way:

```java
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
// more imports...

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {ProxyConfiguration.SPRING_CONTEXT_CONFIGURATION_LOCATIONS})
@Category(Integration.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)
public class MyTest {
    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MyTest.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        log.info("Blah blah");
    }
}
```

I would expect Maven's `Console Output` to display this log, but it doesn't. Yet it appears when I run the test locally on IntelliJ with a Run Configuration of type `JUnit`.

What am I supposed to do to get my logs to show up in the `Console Output` ?

The answers I find online mention wanting to see the logging even when the tests succeed: that would also be a requirement of mine. However, their questions implied that it was already logging when their tests were failing, yet that's not what is happening here. The only thing I get from my test is the stacktrace when an Exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague made me realize that the logs were being output in `target/surefire-reports/my.package.TestClassName-output.txt`.

Turns out the `redirectTestOutputToFile` flag of our `maven-surefire-plugin` was set to `true`. I found that out by reading the output of `mvn clean verify --debug`.

So the `pom.xml` ends up looking something like that (I've removed a whole bunch of irrelevant stuff):

```xml
<project>
    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.28</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Make sure you exclude any conflicting versions from your other dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>${logToFile}</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And now you can use `logToFile` JVM argument to manipulate where the logging goes. Not providing any value for that variable will have it default to `false`, which is what we wanted. Alternatively, we have the option to output to a report file with `mvn clean verify -DlogToFile=true`.

The documentation concerning surefire's flags is there: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile